# Grails resource plugin and using different resources per environment

Tags: grails, resources, minify

In my current grails project we're minifying our JavaScript files with UglifyJS and are also using these minified resources in the development environment. As you can image this is a little pain in the ass to debug on a minified version, fix the bug in the not-minified one, minify it and debug again. Therefore I'd like to include the not-minified versions within the development environment and the minified ones in production. So I tried adjusting the ApplicationResources.groovy to have the following scheme:

```
environments {
    development {
        modules = {
            core {
                resource url:"js/core.js"
            }
        }
    }
    production {
        modules = {
            core {
                resource url:"js/core.min.js"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This somehow doesn't work and exceptions are thrown such as

```
Caused by GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <r:layoutResources>: No module found with name [core]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Update:

I'm not sure I understand this correctly. I tried the following which doesn't work either:

Update:

Adding ids does the trick :)

ApplicationResources.groovy

```
modules = {
    core {
        resource id: 'core', url:"js/core.min.js"
    }
}
```

DevelopmentResources.groovy

```
environment {
    development {
        modules = {
            overrides {
                core {
                    resource id: 'core', url:"js/core.js"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try defining dev and prod resources modules in separate files. like StaticResources.groovy and ProductionResources.groovy.

> Each Resources file ultimately provides Grails with one "modules" closure, Grails then combines the definitions from the closures provided by each file to produce the final configuration.

Here's the [complete nabble discussion](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Environment-Configuration-in-Resources-Files-is-that-possible-Not-working-anyway-td3985335.html).

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you right but I added what I tried in my original post and it doesn't work either :/

Comment: Alright so what's doing the trick is to assign ids. Then the solution you pointed me to works well. Thanks!